# Enumerating WMI on Windows Server 2016 is significantly slower

Tags: performance, vbscript, wmi, enumeration, windows-server-2016

I am using a simple vb script to get CPU0's load percentage, but the WMI enumeration is significantly slower on Windows Server 2016 then older versions and I need to optimize the speed.

Here's my short script:

```
Option Explicit
Dim objWMIService, processItems, objitem, loadpercentage
loadpercentage= 0

Set objWMIService = GetObject("winmgmts:\\.\root\cimv2")

Set processItems = objWMIService.ExecQuery("SELECT * FROM Win32_Processor _
                   WHERE DeviceID='CPU0'", "WQL", wbemFlagReturnImmediately + wbemFlagForwardOnly)

For Each objItem In processItems 
    loadpercentage =  objItem.LoadPercentage
Next
```

There's a 10 second delay between setting processItems and entering the For Each loop. This same script on older versions of Windows Servers takes 2 seconds. Can anything be done to optimize the WMI enumeration? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why are WMI Queries so slow sometimes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1423981/why-are-wmi-queries-so-slow-sometimes)

Comment: If these [sugguestions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/windows/desktop/WmiSdk/improving-enumeration-performance) don't help and it's only on a specific machine I would look to that machines network stack being the issue rather than WMI.

Answer (score 0):

Try to not use * in your WQL queries. No filtering by any property just slows WMI queries very much. Instead of that, specify exacly the properties you need and nothing else:

```
SELECT LoadPercentage FROM Win32_Processor WHERE DeviceID='CPU0'
```

Comment: Thank you for the response. I tried that but it unfortunately did not make a noticeable difference.